# Bulk creation of content page (in SitePages)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, xml, content

I have been asked if it is possible to do a bulk creation of a number of pages, into the "SitePages" folder on SharePoint 2013.

I have seen some references on the web of how to achieve this via XML, but with little success.

Ideally, I would like to have an XML file, that has a structure similar to this

- Page title
- Page content (either flat, or HTML)

I would then see me parsing a file stored in c:\, and the powershell would loop through and create each page.

Would this be possible?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Format your code as such.  Let's say you want to create 10 new pages.

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "url of your site"
$myWeb =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($Web)

$myLayout = $myWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts() | Where { $_.Name -eq "BlankLayout.aspx" }

for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
   $myNewPage = myWeb.AddPublishingPage("Page" + $i + ".aspx", $myLayout)
   $myNewPage.Updated()
   $myNewPage.CheckIn("")
   $myNewPage.ListItem.File.Publish("")
  }
 $Web.Dispose()
```

The BlankLayout file is the layout you created for the empty pages.  in the AddPublishingPage function, I am concatinating Page#.aspx with i, so it'll be Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx, so on.  I think it can work like that.  Just find a way to make a new page name during the loop.  You can then change the number based on how many pages you would like to create.

Here is my source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/12c55fb2-aa44-4d05-b793-7209da37db71/create-a-sharepoint-webpart-page-using-powershell?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I was hoping to be able to have an XML that I could parse with my content. Is that something I could add into this code snippet?